# Memory Leak on using PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, phone-state-listener, leakcanary

I am trying to use `PhoneStateListener` to notify my application when an incoming call triggers so as to perform some action. I register my `PhoneStateListener` in `onResume()` method of my activity as follows.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     tmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     incomingCallListener=new IncomingCallListener();
     tmgr.listen(incomingCallListener, phoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

`onPause()` method of my activity i remove the listener using the following code.

```
     @Override
     protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
        incomingCallListener=null;
        tmgr.listen(incomingCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        tmgr=null;
     }
```

My Incoming class is defined as an inner class in the same activity as follows:

```
    public class IncomingCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

      public IncomingCallListener() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            if (qInProgress) {
                if (qSource.equals(Loading.TYPE_FUN) || (qResumable)) {
                    //Allow to Resume
                } else {
                    //Break and send abort
                    sendAbort();
                }
            }

        }
      }
   }
```

I am using LeakCanary lib to check memory leak and i am getting a memory leak of 6.1Mb from my activity.

[image: Memory Leak]

`sendAbort()` is the method in my activity which does few operations.

Can someone guide me how to take care of this issue? I am struggling with memory management.

Comment: Got some idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40539708/2006283

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which stopped creating memory leak.

```
private static PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener=new PhoneStateListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            if (st_qScreen.qInProgress) {
                if (st_qScreen.qSource.equals(Loading.TYPE_FUN) || (st_qScreen.qResumable)) {
                    //Allow to Resume
                } else {
                    //Break and send abort
                    st_qScreen.sendAbortQ();
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Here st_qScreen is an instance of the current class.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     tmgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     tmgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    tmgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    tmgr=null;
}
```

I set phoneStateListener to null in onDestroy method.

For me this is not creating memory leaks anymore.